# TensorFlow Auto neon-glow-effect

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wrote a piece of code to achieve the effect of neon lights but the effect is not good.

**Here is code.**

```
import os

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import glorot_uniform
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Activation, ZeroPadding2D, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image


def input_data():
    path_x = "data/train/trainA/"
    path_y = "data/train/trainB/"
    train_num = sum([len(x) for _, _, x in os.walk(os.path.dirname(path_x))])
    print(train_num)
    image_train_1 = np.zeros((train_num, 1024, 1024, 3))
    label_train_1 = np.zeros((train_num, 1024, 1024, 3))
    count = 0
    for i in range(train_num):
        img = image.load_img(path_x + "test (" + str(i + 1) + ").png")
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        image_train_1[count] = x
        img = image.load_img(path_y + "test (" + str(i + 1) + ").png")
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        label_train_1[count] = x
        count += 1
    return image_train_1, label_train_1


def test_data():
    path_x = "data/train/testA/"
    path_y = "data/train/testB/"
    test_num = sum([len(x) for _, _, x in os.walk(os.path.dirname(path_x))])
    print(test_num)
    test_x = np.zeros((test_num, 1024, 1024, 3))
    test_y = np.zeros((test_num, 1024, 1024, 3))
    count = 0
    for i in range(test_num):
        img = image.load_img(path_x + "test (" + str(i + 1) + ").png")
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        test_x[count] = x
        img = image.load_img(path_y + "test (" + str(i + 1) + ").png")
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        test_y[count] = x
        count += 1
    return test_x, test_y


def filterModel(input_shape=(1024, 1024, 3)):
    shape = Input(input_shape)
    x = ZeroPadding2D((0, 0))(shape)
    x = Conv2D(32, (9, 9), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name='conv1', kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform(seed=0))(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name='conv2', kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform(seed=0))(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name='conv3', kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform(seed=0))(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    output = Conv2D(3, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', name='conv5', kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform(seed=0))(
        x)
    model1 = Model(inputs=shape, outputs=output, name='FilterModel')
    return model1


# trainData
image_train, label_train = input_data()
image_train = image_train.astype('float32')
label_train = label_train.astype('float32')
image_train /= 255
label_train /= 255
# testData
test_x, test_y = test_data()
test_x = test_x.astype('float32')
test_y = test_y.astype('float32')
test_x /= 255
test_y /= 255
# training
model = filterModel((1024, 1024, 3))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.000003), loss="mean_squared_error",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()
model.fit(image_train, label_train, validation_data=(test_x, test_y), epochs=100, batch_size=2)
model.save("filterModel.h5")
print("Model save done!")
```

**model summary**

```
Model: "FilterModel"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 1024, 1024, 3)]   0         
_________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d (ZeroPadding2 (None, 1024, 1024, 3)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)               (None, 1024, 1024, 32)    7808      
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 1024, 1024, 32)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2 (Conv2D)               (None, 1024, 1024, 64)    18496     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 1024, 1024, 64)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3 (Conv2D)               (None, 1024, 1024, 128)   73856     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 1024, 1024, 128)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv5 (Conv2D)               (None, 1024, 1024, 3)     9603      
=================================================================
Total params: 109,763
Trainable params: 109,763
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I conducted 100 rounds of training because the accuracy and loss will hardly change after that.

result:

test_x | predict | test_y

[Input&Predict&Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn7yI.png)

[Input&Predict&Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aaEr.png)

How to optimize this model?
Or are there other ways to achieve this effect?